# prove or disprove: if Span(s) is a subset of span(t) then s is a subset of t?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the opposite is true, for example if s is a subset of t then span(s) is a subset of span(t) however, I am not sure if the above is accurate. Can I see an example?

Comment: Try thinking of a simple case where $s$ and $t$ each have one element.

Comment: Does this make sense? Assume s=(1) and t=(2) therefore s is not a subset of t. However, span(s) is all multiples of 1 and span(t) would be all multiples of 2 which would be a subset of t?

Comment: In this example I assume the vector space is $\mathbb R$, in which case $span(1)=span(2)=\mathbb R$; but yes $\{1\}$ is not a subset of $\{2\}$ or vice-versa.